# How to find the coordinates of a CStatusBar in an MDI window?

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi

I created a bottom status bar in my MDI window in my `MAINFRAME.cpp` file within the `OnCreate` handler like so:

```
static UINT indicators[] =
{
    ID_SEPARATOR
};

int MainFrm::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
     if (!m_wndStatusBar.Create(this) ||
            !m_wndStatusBar.SetIndicators(indicators,
              sizeof(indicators)/sizeof(UINT)))
     {
        TRACE("Failed to create status bar\n");
        return -1;       // fail to create
     }
}
```

The `CStatusBar` Create function looks like so:

```
virtual BOOL Create(CWnd* pParentWnd,
        DWORD dwStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_BOTTOM,
        UINT nID = AFX_IDW_STATUS_BAR)
```

I am trying to find the coordinates of this status bar, i.e. it's `x` position, but having some difficulty doing so. According to Spy++ on a monitor with resolution of 1920x1080, the status bar's x.top position = `1055`.

I've attempted, but got x.top = `66`:

```
RECT rect;
m_wndStatusBar.GetWindowRect(&rect);
int x_top_pos = rect.top;
```

I've also attemped, but got x_top_pos = `2`:

```
m_wndStatusBar.GetItemRect(0, &rect);
```

Those are the only 2 functions that returns a `RECT` object, but both return the incorrect values.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMainFrame::OnCreate` is called too early, the windows are not positioned yet. I created MDI application in Visual Studio 2015, when this code is called from `OnCreate`:

```
RECT rect;
m_wndStatusBar.GetWindowRect(&rect);
```

it gives the rectangle `{LT(440, 74) RB(440, 74)  [0 x 0]}`. So, you need to call this later. For example, I moved the code to `CreateDockingWindows`:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::CreateDockingWindows()
{
    // ....

    RECT rect;
    m_wndStatusBar.GetWindowRect(&rect);
    return TRUE;
}
```

`rect` is `{LT(440, 873) RB(1864, 892)  [1424 x 19]}`
Another option is to post user-defined message to itself (from `CMainFrame::OnCreate`) and find the status bar rectangle in the message handler.